# NonUniqueObjectException when persisting object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi Guys I have a problem with Hibernate when trying to write an array of object to the db.  Essential I have an object built from a web service query.  This object 'response' can have contain a maximum of ten 'unpaid items', my problem arises when I try to persist these.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
public class AccountDetailsRROutput implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id

    private String payeename;

    private String typeunpd;

    private BigDecimal unpdamt;

    @Column(name="TRANSACTION_ID")
    private long transactionId;

    public AccountDetailsRROutput() {
        super();
    }

    // plus all get/sets
}



        //================================================================
        //  Populate the output for the repeating rows table
        //  which can contain a maximum of 10 unpaid items
        //===============================================================
        AccountDetailsRROutput outputRRTable[] = new AccountDetailsRROutput[response.getLineItems().length];

        LOGGER.debug(METHOD_NAME, "Loop through the line items");
        for (int i = 0; i < response.getLineItems().length; i++) {

            //================================================================
            //  Ensure that we have an item so we don't write an empty row
            //================================================================
            if (response.getLineItems()[i].getTypeunpd() == null || response.getLineItems()[i].getTypeunpd() == "") {
                LOGGER.debug(METHOD_NAME, "No unpaid item entry so break out of the the loop");
                break;
            }
            else {
                LOGGER.debug(METHOD_NAME, "We've got an unpaid item so add the details to the DB");

                outputRRTable[i] = new AccountDetailsRROutput();

                outputRRTable[i].setTransactionId(iTransactionID);
                outputRRTable[i].setTypeunpd(response.getLineItems()[i].getTypeunpd());
                outputRRTable[i].setPayeename(response.getLineItems()[i].getPayeeName());
                outputRRTable[i].setUnpdAmt(response.getLineItems()[i].getUnpdAmt());

                //================================================================
                //  Persist the output list DB object
                //================================================================
                LOGGER.debug(METHOD_NAME, "Persist repeating rows table DB object for line item: " + (i+1));
                em_i.persist(outputRRTable[i]);             
            }
        }
    LOGGER.debug(METHOD_NAME, "Finished persisting repeating rows table DB object");
    em_i.flush();
```

When I try this I get the following error:

org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:

I can get around this my changing emi.persist to emi.merge but it is only writing one element to the db.  There can be duplicate records in this table and there is no pk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have more than one item with the same `payeename`. Try defining another id (for example an id composed of `payeename` and `transactionID`).

Comment: Hey thanks so much much for this you were correct.  I was losing my marbles a bit on this cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As per your hibernate mapping `payeename` is your primary key which means there can be only one entry per `payeename` in your database, the exception says `NonUniqueObjectException` which indicate that you are trying to `persist` another row with the same primary key.

**Solution**:

1. Before inserting, make sure there is no entry in the database with the primary key.
2. If the primary key already exist instead of insert a new record, do an update.

Hope it helps.